# Why is 'Fix All Issues' always disabled in Xcode 13/14/15 beta?

Tags: xcode, xcode14, xcode15

I know this has been asked before for Xcode 9 or whatever. But it's been years now since I've seen it working. Does anyone know why? I mean, cleaning, restarting, deleting derived data doesn't do anything. It doesn't matter if there are multiple issues or one. If they are complex or trivial.

Comment: Hey just got the same issue, have you got a way to fix it? I'm on Xcode 15.2 rn